# Backup and Restore strategy in Hbase cluster

Tags: backup-restoration, hadoop, hbase

I have just started with Hbase cluster. I have a Hbase cluster with 2 master nodes and 4 slave nodes. I have one hbase table where huge data is populated everyday so the disk gets filled quickly. I would like to implement a backup and restore strategy in this table. I would like to delete old data (so that disk gets free), store them in some storage like S3 and later if needed, restore them.

I have a large mysql table where data are stored in partition (based on day). I delete old partition and back them up in a Blob storage. I would like to implement similar capabilities in Hbase cluster.

The main objective is to free the disk from old data but also capable to restore them when needed. I did some research but I could not find good tutorial or documentation on this.